# Escape последовательность в printf

Tags: c, форматирование, printf, escape

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-нибудь способ изменять количество отступов (в данном случае "3") в такой конструкции "%3d" с помощью цикла for, чтобы несколько вызовов printf были с разным количеством отступов?

Comment: Конечно, ты же можешь сам формировать строку форматирования, а потом передавать ее в printf

Answer (score 5):

Вместо литерала (`%3d`) ширину поля можно задать звёздочкой (`%*d`). В списке аргументов должно быть целое значение с действительной шириной:

```
//        ширина
//        ------ 
//       |      |
//       v      |
printf("%*d\n", w, d);
//        ^        |
//        |        |
//         --------
//         значение
```

[printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

> - (optional) integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. ... In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the argument to be converted ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int d = 123;
    for (int w = 0; w < 20; ++w) {
        printf("%*d\n", w, d);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc pad.c
>
> $ ./a.out 
> 123
> 123
> 123
> 123
>  123
>   123
>    123
>     123
>      123
>       123
>        123
>         123
>          123
>           123
>            123
>             123
>              123
>               123
>                123
>                 123
> ```

Comment: Благодарю! То, что мне было нужно!